# mvc Groupby and Orderby nested

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

mvc beginner
I have a table of lots that contain a property `Num_of_steps` representing the number of completed steps toward building a house.

I currently use this to retrieve the lot information and am sorting by the lot number.

```
        var ViewModel = new Sub_lot_VM();
        ViewModel.Subdivisions = db.Subdivisions
            .Include(i => i.Lots)
            .ToList();
        if (ViewModel.Subdivisions !=null)   // if data sort by lot number
        {
           foreach (var item in ViewModel.Subdivisions)
              item.Lots = item.Lots.OrderBy(i => i.LotName).ToList();
        }
        return View(ViewModel);
    }
```

Now I want to display this information a 3 groups:

**first** where the count is between 1 and 114 (active),

**second** where the count is above 115 (or GTE 115?)  (finished)( and then orderby lot name) and

**third** group is count = 0 (not started) also order by lotname.

I've been trying to think of how to add .where and .groupby lambda expressions to my method without luck. Such as`.where(I=>i.Lot.Num_of_steps=0)`.

I also see that I needed a `foreach` where some LINQ examples did not need the `foreach`. Still confused on that.

Comment: I've read through your question a few times and I can't make heads or tails of it. Can you help us out by doing the following?  Give us your inputs (and class structure) and the Outputs you expect, given those inputs. Also, please make your question explicit.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, I think he's asking for a `Select`. A way to divide up the SubDivision lists into 3 parts, based on the num_of_steps property.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think I understand what it's about, looks like the OP did some effort. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @GertArnold If you can understand what's going on, can you edit the question into shape?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'll give it a shot. I also hope my answer will explain some bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the lots first and then use `groupby` with ranges to get the groups

```
from x in
(
    db.Subdivisions.SelectMany(sd => sd.Lots)
)
group x by x.Num_of_steps == 0 ? 3 : x.Num_of_steps < 115 ? 1 : 2 into g 
orderby g.Key
select g.OrderBy(g1 => g1.LotName)
```

You can give the groups meaningful names in stead of 1, 2 and 3, but you can also postpone that until it's display time. The numbers facilitate correct sorting.

Comment: I think this is it. Where do I learn about the ==0?3 and 1:2 constructions.

Comment: paqogomez correctly read the question. Divide the lots into 3 groups. Where count = 0 then count gte 115 and lastly between 1 and 114 with the proper orderbys. I'll give a try and report soon

Comment: It's the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). In other languages know as "immediate if".

Comment: Thank you all. I will do more reading on the conditional operator and syntax. I've also give the green arrow! many thanks